# MySQL Union query duplicate/group by

Tags: mysql, sql

`(SELECT *  FROM Reports WHERE Modulo = "Reports"  )  UNION ( SELECT *  FROM Reports_Copy WHERE Modulo = "Reports" );`

I have two tables, at the time of union gives me the results in both tables, but I want to see the results of reports and also those who are in the copy of the report that are not table report.

```
tables
REPORTS
ID/Modulo/Name
1/REPORTS/JANE 
2/REPORTS/JOSE
3/REPORTS/ANA
```

REPORTS_COPY

```
ID|Modulo /Name
1 /REPORTS/JANE 
2 /REPORTS/JOSE
3 /REPORTS/ANA
4 /REPORTS/DAVID
```

RESULT==
   `(SELECT *  FROM Reports WHERE Modulo = "Reports"  )  UNION ( SELECT *  FROM Reports_Copy WHERE Modulo = "Reports" );`

```
ID/Modulo /Name
1 /REPORTS/JANE 
1 /REPORTS/JANE 
2 /REPORTS/JOSE
2 /REPORTS/JOSE
3 /REPORTS/ANA
3 /REPORTS/ANA
4 /REPORTS/DAVID
```

THE RESULT THAT I WANT

```
ID|Modulo /Name
1 /REPORTS/JANE 
2 /REPORTS/JOSE
3 /REPORTS/ANA
4 /REPORTS/DAVID
```

Comment: Usually, `UNION` already gives you only the unique rows. Are you not selecting more fields, or perhaps mistakenly using a `UNION ALL`?

Comment: this is exactly your SQL fiddle, tell me whats wrong here.http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0a89/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a `union`, just by filtering on the second subquery:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM Reports r
WHERE Modulo = 'Reports'
UNION ALL
SELECT rc.*
FROM Reports_Copy rc
WHERE Modulo = 'Reports' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM REPORTS R WHERE RC.ID = R.ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Union alone works:

```
select * from REPORTS where Modulo = 'REPORTS'
union
select * from REPORTS_COPY where Modulo = 'REPORTS'
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85439a/2